# WPF Continuous Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm trying to make some images loop round, kind of like what you'd see in a slot machine.
My current code is more of a marquee so the images go from the top to the bottom and while they're moving theres some whitespace behind the first image.

How can I make it so the last image immediately follows the first image in a loop?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SlotV3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Slot Machine" Height="600" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="634,185,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Canvas Name="canvas1" Margin="82,49,458,12" ClipToBounds="True" Height="500">
        <StackPanel Height="1043" Name="stackPanel1" Width="193" Canvas.Left="28" Canvas.Top="8">
            images here...
        </StackPanel>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and the animation code I'm using:

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.From = -stackPanel1.ActualHeight;
        da.To = canvas1.ActualHeight;
        da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25));
        da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        stackPanel1.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, da);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following way is easier. Try using this event:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(CompositionTarget_Rendering);
    }

    void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle smoke = new Rectangle();
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(smoke);
        smoke.Y -= 5;
    }
}
```

This is a pseudocode, but this strategy will make an object run from the bottom to the top.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx#Y228